# PostgresSQL query for matching a subset on a column

Tags: database

I have a table looks like this:

EventID | Status
--------+------------

1       | Starting
1       | Processing
1       | Ended
2       | Starting

2       | Processing
3       | Starting

How can I write a query to get the EventId that is not yet 'Ended'? return like:

### EventID

2

3

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to use subqueries. You want a subquery of `eventid` values that you want to filter out of the main query. In other words, you don't want `select eventid from events where status='Ended'`. And you will link this subquery to your main query using the `not in` keyword.

First let's load some sample data.

```
create table events(EventID numeric, Status varchar);
insert into events values(1, 'Starting');
insert into events values(1, 'Processing');
insert into events values(1, 'Ended');
insert into events values(2, 'Starting');
insert into events values(2, 'Processing');
insert into events values(3, 'Starting');
commit
select * from events;
```

> eventid |   status
> ---------+------------

> ```
>   1 | Starting
>   1 | Processing
>   1 | Ended
>   2 | Starting
>   2 | Processing
>   3 | Starting
> ```
>
> (6 rows)

And here is your desired query with the subquery filter.

```
select eventid from events where eventid not in (select eventid from events where status='Ended');
```

> eventid
>
> ---
>
> ```
>   2
>   2
>   3
> ```
>
> (3 rows)

Comment: This works well in my situation. Thank you.